# What question (or answer) on the Stack Exchange network has accumulated the most downvotes?

Tags: discussion

Or the most negative rating?

(no need for an answer that's completely right - I'll also take anything that has an especially high number, as it might be interesting to identify trends).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/871405/why-do-i-need-an-ioc-container-as-opposed-to-straightforward-di-code/871420#871420 +224, -191

Comment: and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905734/how-to-send-100-000-emails-weekly

Answer (score 5):

**`For questions`**:

This may not be the correct answer but steps to find the most down-voted question on a given SE site:

Go to the site of your choice, say [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?page=40465&sort=votes).

Click on questions and then click on Votes.

[image: Homepage]

Scroll down to the bottom and click on the last page.

[image: Scroll to bottom]

Scroll down to the bottom and there is your answer.

[image: Most downvoted]

**`For answers`**:

You have to query and find out from https://data.stackexchange.com/

Comment: +1, I went through http://data.stackexchange.com/ but that's far simpler!

Comment: @awoodland: For answers, you still have to go through data explorer.